# Getting auto incremented value in MySQL for a single row insert statement

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, unixodbc

I have an MySQL database where in a large number of threads are performing inserts into a table. The ID column in this table needs to be unique and I was trying to get this to be an auto-incremented column however is there a way to return the auto incremented integer value as part of the insert? I need this ID value for my in-memory cache or do I need to perform another query to get at the auto-incremented ID value?

I am using odbc on linux to connect to a MySQL instance also running on Linux.

Comment: Last_insert_id?

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific in your question about your particular application, framework, language which you use to get this value. This matters. In general MySQL documentation describes:

- [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function to obtain the value
- Recommendations on [Obtaining Auto-Increment Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html)
- Example in C [How to Get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)